# How to increase the height of view in Android?

Tags: java, android

I created view the middle of layout in Android application. But I want it to be increase the height of view by pressing the binary number on keypad. I don't have any idea how to implement it.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/textstr" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#9400d3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Add an ID to your view.

2) In coding:
try something like this:

```
view_object.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,160));
```

Comment: I mention the above description when i press any number on the keypad my my view height is increased.